# Show data into Select tag in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5, laravel-5.6

I need to get data into select tag in laravel,i am using html tags to show data in laravel.

i have company and branch, i need to select a company and type branch under a compnay so i need to list company and select a compnay but it show error variable compnaies not found,please help me to fix this

Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Branch;
use App\Company;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class BranchController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $companies=Company::where('status','0')
            ->get();


    return view('branch.index',['Company'=>$companies]);
        return view('branch.index');
    }

    public function create()
    {

    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {


            $branch =Branch::create([
                'name' =>$request->input('name'),
                'comp_id' =>$request->input('comp_id'),
                'dlr_id' =>$request->input('dlr_id'),

            ]);

            if($branch){
                return redirect()->with('success','Branch Created Successfully');
            }


        return back()->withInput()->with('error','Error Creating New Branch');


    }

       public function show(Branch $branch)
    {
        //
    }

       public function edit(Branch $branch)
    {
        //
    }

    public function update(Request $request, Branch $branch)
    {
        //
    }


    public function destroy(Branch $branch)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

index.blade.php

```
div class="page-content-wrapper ">

<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="page-title-box">
                <div class="btn-group float-right">

                </div>
                <h4 class="page-title">Branch Management</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end page title end breadcrumb -->

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="card m-b-30">
                <div class="card-body">

                    <h4 class="mt-0 header-title">Branch</h4>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <form method="post" action="{{route('branch.store')}}">
                        {{csrf_field()}}
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Company</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">

                                    <select class="form-control" id="compnay" name="compnay">

                                        <option>Select Company</option>
                                        @foreach($companies as $companies)
                                        <option value="{{$companies->comp_id}}">{{$companies->name}}</option>
                                        @endforeach

                                    </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Dealership</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <select class="form-control" id="dealer" name=" dealer">

                                    <option>Select Dealer</option>
                                    <option></option>

                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="example-text-input" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Branch Name</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="branch" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <div class="page-title-box">
                                    <div class="btn-group float-right">
                                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Button</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </form>


                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: It should be `return view('branch.index',['companies'=>$companies]);` because you are using the plural in your template.

Comment: Thanks it worked ...thanks man